# Ubercart - shipping not working for same state shipping

Tags: drupal, ubercart, usps

So suddenly my shipping will not show show for the same state in which my store is located or for a neighboring state but will work for states on the west and east cost.

I'm using USPS for shipping, Drupal v. 7.2x and Ubercart v. 7-3.6

I haven't seen any errors in either the Devel module or server log.  I simply get the standard "There was a problem obtaining your shipping rates.." error message on the check out pane.

I'm wondering if it is an issue on USPS's end. I haven't contacted them at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so it looks like the USPS module (or USPS themselves) no longer allows Parcel Post for local deliveries i.e. deliveries within the same state that the store is located.  This is also true for "near by" states.

I’m not sure at what point the Parcel Post (now shown as Standard Post) option is allowed, but I can tell you it is allowed on states that are further away compared to a bordering state.  So at some given distance, Standard Post becomes a viable option.

So, I had to enable a second USPS option - Priority Mail.  When it comes to same state / “near by” states shipping, the USPS shipping quotes will **only allow priority mail**.

Now, with out of state shipping, such as California and Florida, the customer will have a choice between Standard Post and Priority Mail 2-Day.